# Only Want a user to 'like' a comment once. My code is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have Post model, that has a field likes_total on it. I only want a user to be able to like a post once, but the code for this in the view is not working. here is the code:

views.py

```
def like(request, post_id, group_id):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk= group_id)
    post =  get_object_or_404(Post, pk= post_id)
    likers = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user in likers:
            return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group':group, 'error': "you have already liked this post"} )
        else:
            post.likes_total += 1
            post.save()
            likers.append(request.user)
            return redirect('/groups/' + str(group_id) )
        # post.save()
    else:
        return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group':group})
```

this code seems right to me, cant tell what the problem is.. any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: But here you use a local list. You understand that the database is the only persistent data in a webserver?

Answer (score 1):

Every time your function is called you set likers to be empty. Instead it should be an attribute of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your `likers` list isn't persisted anywhere and it's always initialized to an empty list, so the `request.user` will never be in the list.

You should edit your model so that each of your `Post` objects have a list of users that liked it, and then you can persist, update and check that list to ensure that each user likes each post once at most.

Answer (score 0):

You define a list named `likers` *in* the `like` function. That means that each time someone calls the `like` function, you construct a *new* and empty list.

You could construct the list outside the function, but this will not help either. In fact the only data that you can consider *persistent* (the data that you can insert/modify/delete such that the next call sees this differences) is in the database.

As a result you should let the database store the people who like the post, by for example adding a `ManyToManyField` to the `Post` model that refers to the users that liked to post. So you should edit the model:

```
class Post(Model):

    likers = ManyToManyField(User)
    # some other fields
    likes_total = IntegerField()
```

Now we can add the user that likes the post to the many-to-many relation:

```
def like(request, post_id, group_id):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk= group_id)
    post =  get_object_or_404(Post, pk= post_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user in post.likers.all():
            return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group':group, 'error': "you have already liked this post"} )
        else:
            post.likes_total += 1
            post.likers.add(request.user)
            post.save()
            return redirect('/groups/' + str(group_id) )
    else:
        return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group':group})
```

Another improvement that you can make is using `reverse` to generate urls, instead of constructing URLs yourself.